# Convert amount digit to word like 1 million = 10 Lakh

Tags: c#, winforms

Can anybody give me a primer code I could work on in converting numbers into words?
I search the code and I get it but there is no code or answer what I want.
for example:
The number `1101011101`. I want to convert it to:

- One billion One hundred One million and Eleven Thousand One hundred and one
- 110 Crore 10 Lakh 11 Thousand One hundred and one
- 1 Arab 10 Crore 10 Lakh and 11 Thousand One hundred and one

Please help me to generate this code.I want both ways in one function text-box return value to label.on text-changed event
Thanks

Comment: if anyone answers this, you'll have achieved maximum output for minimum input, just like your bio states...

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. What have you tried. Where are you stuck? Look at the dupe and you should be able to adapt it pretty easily.

Comment: I give you all detail, you don't understand what I am saying?

Comment: user1666620 you write this is duplicate question . then give me the link who ask this type of question.I am saying to convert it. 1101011101 = 1 Arab 10 Crore 10 Lakh and 11 Thousand One hundred and one

Comment: If you want me to give you code tell me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Humanizr](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#number-to-words) library for this.

Example:

```
1.ToWords() => "one"
10.ToWords() => "ten"
11.ToWords() => "eleven"
122.ToWords() => "one hundred and twenty-two"
3501.ToWords() => "three thousand five hundred and one"
```

Supports cultures:

```
1.ToWords(GrammaticalGender.Masculine, new CultureInfo("ru")) => "один"
```